# Point evaluation of a linear functional on an Ultrapower

Tags: functional-analysis, model-theory

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $(E)_{\mathcal U}$ be an ultrapower for some ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on an index set $I$.

It is remarked in a paper that $(E')_{\mathcal U}$ can be *naturally* embedded into $(E)_{\mathcal U}'$ (where I use $'$ to indicate the normed space dual).

I just want to clarify that this natural embedding is given by the following action.

$$(\varphi_{i})_{\mathcal U}:(x_{i})_{\mathcal U}\mapsto \lim_{i\to\mathcal U}\varphi_{i}(x_{i})$$

Is this correct?  (sorry if I chose poor tags)

---

$\bf{\text{Definition}}$:

$\lim_{i\to \mathcal U}x_i = x$ in a topological space $X$ if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x, \{i\in I : x_i\in U\}\in \mathcal U$.

Comment: How is this limit defined exactly? Is it guaranteed to exist?

Comment: It is guaranteed to exist in any compact space. Since the indexed family is bounded in the scalar field this is enough.   Ill add the definition to the question for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s correct. It works because $E_{\mathscr{U}}$ isn’t the full model-theoretic ultrapower: we consider only bounded sequences $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, so that $\mathscr{U}\text{-}\lim_k\|x_k\|$ exists, and we set $\|x\|_\infty=\mathscr{U}\text{-}\lim_k\|x_k\|$. That already cuts out the infinite elements of the full ultrapower, and in addition we take the quotient by the ideal $\{x:\|x\|_\infty=0\}$, identifying infinitesimally different elements.

Similarly, if $\langle\varphi_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle_{\mathscr{U}}\in(E')_{\mathscr{U}}$, then by definition there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\{\|\varphi_k\|:k\in U\}$ is bounded. It follows that there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $\{\varphi_k(x_k):k\in U\}$ is bounded and hence that $\mathscr{U}\text{-}\lim\varphi_k(x_k)$ exists, and it’s straightforward to verify that the map is a bounded linear functional on $E_{\mathscr{U}}$.

Comment: @Kyle: You’re welcome!